# Php seven update messed up my program

Tags: php, mysqli

So recently with the php 7 update they removed all the mysql commands. however one of my programs for my internship was using such commands in one of the pages. however when i change it to mysqli it no longer works like it should. can someone help perhaps?

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or die("Error " . mysqli_error());

//select MySQLi dabatase table
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "table") or die("Error " . mysqli_error());


$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM gebiedsmanagers WHERE Datum >= NOW()");
```

[Pastebin code](https://pastebin.com/aLExQP9s)
With kind regards,
Dayne Tersluijsen

Comment: Looking in a manual is 10x times faster than writing a question. `mysqli_select_db($con, "prodyne")`

Comment: To be fair, every `mysql_*()` page of the PHP manual has had a deprecated notice on it for several years. You really should not have been using those functions in the first place.

Comment: as much as i would love to agree with you we get taught at school and they didn't tell us anything about that. so it's not exactly my fault either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given:
mysqli_select_db("prodyne", $con);
```

**To**

```
mysqli_select_db($con, "prodyne")
```

---

**Try this out!**

```
    <?php


    //MySQLi information

    $db_host     = "localhost";
    $db_username = "username";
    $db_password = "password";

    //connect to mysqli database (Host/Username/Password)
    $connection = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or die("Error " . mysqli_error());

    //select MySQLi dabatase table
    $db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "table") or die("Error " . mysqli_error());

    //fetch information from your database
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM gebiedsmanagers WHERE Datum >= NOW()");
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

               {   
                  $counter ++;

?>
<tr><td><?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['Datum']));?></td><td>
<?php echo $row['Voor1500']; ?></td><td><?php echo $row['Na1500']; ?>
</td></tr>
<?php

             if($counter >= 120) {             
                break;     
          }
```

I hope this has helped you.

Comment: So i tried it and ended up getting a Fatal error: 'break' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context in C:\xampp1\htdocs\ProdyneP\Modules\Welcome.php on line 143 error xD

Comment: From what I see, I set the database connection and fetching data correctly. Seems to be something else you have from another file. You said line 143 ( I don't know what is that and where) Just fixed the code you provided.

Comment: I editted my code so a pastebin is included. could you perhaps take a look? I'd appreciate it

Comment: @Daynie I checked your code and it has a lot of MySQL mixed with MySQLi... Change all of them to MySQLi and implement the way I showed you to connect to the database, and remember always $connection comes first before the fetched item. ($con, "prodyne") not the other way.

Comment: Thanks alot so far xD i just got a different error. unexpected end of file. but i'll figure that one out. thanks alot for the help ^^

Comment: @Daynie You are welcome, I hope this has helped you. Anyways unexpected end of file in most cases means a missing "}" ;)

Comment: yes i realized that.. i figured it oiut... my problem right now is that i get a few different errors... jezus.. can the errors please stop ;-;

Comment: hahaha Mostly about fetch arrays and shit. :S i'll just tell my teacher about them when i get the chance.